# ¿Cómo especificar en una función que un argumento es un data frame, en R?

Tags: r, funciones, dataframe

tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
x<-sample(1:30, 50, T)
y<-sample(90:450, 50, T)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
}
```

Y deseo crear una función en la cual se desarrolle el modelo lineal sólo especificando el data frame. Como se ve a continuación:

```
regresion<-function(x){
  reg<-lm(x[,1]~x[,2], data = x)
  return(summary(reg))
```

Pero como es obvio, el argumento `x` que declaré es un vector y no un data frame.

Cómo tendría que hacer para indicar que el argumento `x` es un data frame.

**Gracias de antemano**

Comment: Si los nombres de las variables son siempre los mismos puedes hacer `reg <- lm(x~y, data = x)` sino la respuesta de mpaladino es lo indicado

Comment: `x` es un data.frame, sin enbargo `x[ ,1]` o `x[ , 2] ` **sí** son vectores, por el subsetting que hace `R`. Tu función funcionaría si eliminas el argumento `data = x`, ya que se puede especificar una regresión con vectores. El error que sale de tu función es difícil de rastrear porque la evaluación de la fórmulas en `R` es complicada. Creo que la mejor alternativa es definir la fórmula con los nombres de columna del data.frame usando el atajo `dependiente~.` para indicar que todas las demás columnas son predictores.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Patricio y mpaladino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías manipular la fórmula de la regresión en lugar de armarla pasándole los datos como vectores. Algo así:

```
regresion<-function(x){
  dependiente <- names(x)[1]
  formula <- as.formula(paste(dependiente, "~."))
  #print(formula) #Para verificar
  reg<-lm(formula, data = x)
  return(summary(reg))
  }
```

De esta forma obtienes un modelo OLS para un data.frame en el que la primera columna es la dependiente y todas las demás independientes.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!